# InputStream from a URL crashing

Tags: java, android, inputstream

I'm very new to all this, but I've been reading stuff all over the place on InputStream to try to get my Android app to read from a URL. My code seems just like all the other stuff but just won't work:

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://www.somewebsite.com");
    URLConnection urlConnection = (URLConnection)url.openConnection();
    InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream(); }
catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace(); }
```

The problem is definitely in the line declaring the InputStream. When I remove it there are no errors. But when it's included I get a fatal error and my program crashes:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
```

This is really confusing to me because my code looks just like both the documentation and other queries I've seen on StackOverflow. And as a point of curiosity, why is my code not catching the Exception? Not that one should be there. Please help guys, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Please show the full stack trace - it's not obvious where it's failing at the moment. (You say it's in the call to `getInputStream`, but that doesn't look right for the exception you've given...)

Comment: Perhaps `e.getMessage()` is null.

Comment: Where do you call `println`

Comment: Correct, I'm pretty sure it is, since I'm not calling println anywhere else. But that still doesn't make sense to me. If println is being called by e.getMessage() then doesn't that mean that an exception has been caught and hence e should not be null?

At any rate, I don't think this is the problem, because there's still an exception being caught and displaying the error. My program still fatally crashes at "in = urlConnection.getInputStream()" even if I don't use try and catch statements. But like I said, I'm new and probably don't know what I'm talking about, so correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: Can you temporary Commenting Log.e line and see if it works, I suspect the way you make your Log.e... is wrong if you run the rest of your code with out Log.e line it should works.

Comment: Jon Skeet I apologize but you may have to bear with me here. By "stack trace" do you mean the entirety of the logcat output? Or just from where the RuntimeException occurs?

Comment: maytham and icetea I feel so stupid, I could have sworn I checked this a half-dozen times before! You're absolutely right, of course. I obviously misunderstand exceptions though, could you help me out? I thought that if my code was operating properly the exception shouldn't be called in the first place. This just seems to be counterintuitive that the error is caused by the Exception being null -- basically the error is that there is no error? Anyway, thanks a lot. This community is great, thanks for your patience with a dope like me :P